# How I can add custom icon in li attribute of ul in html5 using jquery mobile 1.4.2

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I am developing project in phonegap,I want to add custom icon (which is in my project folder) in li attribute of ul(Unorder list)
I am using JQuery mobile1.4.2.js , Jquery mobile1.4.2.css , Jquery2.1.1.js , Jquery1.10.2.js.  I tried,google it but get confused andnot getting required output.
Is there any steps to add custom icon ? If yes then tell me and any source code available then post too...???
Thanx in advanced..

Comment: It sounds like you want to target the bullet point with CSS for an image, is that correct?

Comment: yes i want to use image instead of defult icons

Answer (score 4):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kLKRm/

#### HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="custom">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Europe</li>
    <li><a href="#">Norway</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
.ui-icon-custom:after {
    background-image: url('http://secondavenuesagas.com/images/bullets/1.gif');
}
```

#### Rules

```
data-icon="custom" --> .ui-icon-custom:after
data-icon="puppy" --> .ui-icon-puppy:after
```

Comment: thanx gajotres, can i specify my project folder (in my pc) URL which contain image that i want to use in place of default icon ?

Comment: CSS background-image can accept any location you can provide, just google it.

Comment: Hi @nikhichavan502 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: and why u include javascript code here ? will this helpout in my issue.

Comment: jsFiddle you so is my template I use to help other people, and you don't need it here, everything found in this answer is all you need. Regarding your background-image, you need to use correct relative path. I gave you correct answer (you so it in my example) it is up to you to successfully include it in your code.